# calling function from inside stateless component on button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware that we shouldn't use methods inside stateless component, in my below example i want to explicitly call a method onClick of a button, is there any way to do it? How can i call some function onClick? and let that function have 
{e => { props.handleDelete(props.optionText) } inside it

```
              function Option(props) {
              return (
               <div>
                   <div>
                       <p>{props.optionText}</p>
                      <button
                            onClick={e => {
                                       props.handleDelete(props.optionText)
                                        }}>
                         Remove Item
                    </button>
                 </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you've posted? You can't have methods in a stateless component because it isn't a class, but you can still define and use functions, access props, etc.

Comment: I wanted something like <button onClick={anotherFunction}> Remove Item</button>

Comment: and that another function will have this, e => {
                                       props.handleDelete(props.optionText)
                                        }

Comment: i rephrased my question hope its clear now

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have now, but also nothing to stop you defining said function inside the Option function.

Comment: but the new function gets redefined every time when option component renders, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, with the new values of the props.

Comment: yeah, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: ...the way you already have done it? What's the issue with the now *two* ways you are aware of? What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: nothing wrong in what i've done here, its working perfect, i was just trying to find any other way do it, like by calling it inside another function

Comment: If you don't have a specific problem to solve, it's very difficult to identify an appropriate answer. Please avoid asking broad, speculative questions here and focus on concrete, answerable ones.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
function Option(props) {

  const deleteHandler = (e) => {
    props.handleDelete(props.optionText)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{props.optionText}</p>
        <button
          onClick={deleteHandler}>
          Remove Item
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you see you can just define a function inside your functional component before you return the jsx and pass its pointer to `onClick`.

To prevent recreating the function on every render you can use `React.memo` or `useCallback` hook.

```
  const deleteHandler = useCallback((e) => {
    props.handleDelete(props.optionText)
  }, [props.handleDelete, props.optionText]);
```

Comment: but we shouldn't do this right? because deleteHandler gets defined every time when component renders

Comment: You can also use `useCallback` if you only want to prevent re-render because of the function. I updated my answer.